# Remove all files from a directory except those listed in a file

Tags: unix

got a file like "index.txt" that contains a few lines of book titles like:

```
book 1.pdf<br>
book 1.opf<br>
book2.epub<br>
book3.opf<br>
```

and so more, 1 title = 1 line

Id'd like to do this thing in bash:

```
rm -rf from $dir IF $file IS NOT in index.txt
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below command.

```
find <dir> -name "*" | grep -vFf index.txt | xargs rm -rf
```

> `find` : List all the files in the specified directory 
>  
>   `grep-vFf` : Do inverse grep with input from the file (will list files that are not found in the input file. In this case it is index.txt )
>   `xargs rm -rf` : Delete each of the file that are not found in the
>   list. This deletion list is obtained as the output of previous grep
>   command

Edit:

When files names contain white spaces use the below command.

```
find <dir> -name "*" | grep -vFf index.txt |sed 's/^/"/;s/$/"/' | xargs rm -rf
```

> sed would add quotes to all the files name.

Comment: Some text explaining what the command does and why it works would be nice

Comment: Show `cat libri.txt` and `ls LibriMammaBk`

Comment: @alestark : The reason for not working was that the file names contained spaces in them. Check Edit for update answer.

Comment: Everytime the same.....

jarvis:Desktop ale$ find LibriMamma/ -name "*" | grep -vFf libri.txt | sed 's/^/"/;s/$/"/' | xargs rm -rf

jarvis:Desktop ale$ ls LibriMamma | wc -l
    1899
jarvis:Desktop ale$

Comment: do you have any idea?

Comment: With the same files and the libri.txt file, everything seems to work on my ubuntu PC. No idea why its not working at your end.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the listed files in a txt file using

```
#!/bin/sh

while read line;
do
rm `echo $dir/line`
done<list.txt
```